# Tensorflow simple_save with checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save my model at different steps while training. Let's say I would like to save after 5 epochs.

At this moment I am using:

```
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
            sess, model_folder, inputs, outputs
        )
```

which works as a charm. Nevertheless, I realize it is saving the whole graph and weights on each iteration, which has a high computational cost.

I would like to update the weights of my model keeping the graph from the previous save (since it is not changing during training)

I have read about *tf.train.Saver* which seems to fit with my intentions. But this forces me to specify all the variables I want to save, this is not as practical as *simple_save* method. So I am wondering if there is any way of using *simple_save* in a checkpoint fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong understanding of the `tf.train.Saver`. You can do something as simple as:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for e in range(epochs):
        ...
        if e % 5 == 0:
            saver.save(sess, "/path/where/to/save/model")
```

So no need to specify every single variable you want to save.